NextJS wait until Dom renderd
I have an Issue related to rendering an NextJS App inside MS Teams with Citrix. Without Citrix it is running.
The following error occurs:

Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
VM5:2 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('WebAPP WEBURL') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
sendToIframe @ VM5:2
VM5:2 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('WebAPP WEBURL') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
sendToIframe @ VM5:2
VM5:2 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('WebAPP WEBURL') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
sendToIframe @ VM5:2
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://teams.microsoft.com/service-worker.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I'm working with NextJS and Typescript.

Set header X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://teams.microsoft.com/. Set Content Security Policy headers to allow Teams and any other host applications of your app.
Please refer prerequisites of tab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

This is deprecated based on the offical satements of chrome e.g.

Could you please share the document where it is mentioned that it is deprecated?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

You're correct that the X-Frame-Options header has been deprecated in favor of the Content-Security-Policy (CSP) header, which provides more flexibility and security. The X-Frame-Options header is still supported by many browsers, but it's recommended to use the Content-Security-Policy header instead.

To address the issue you're facing with rendering your NextJS app inside Microsoft Teams with Citrix, you can use the Content-Security-Policy header to allow your app to be embedded in an iframe. Here's an example of how you can set the CSP header:
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://teams.microsoft.com;
This header allows your app to be embedded in an iframe on the specified domains. Make sure to replace https://teams.microsoft.com with the appropriate domain(s) where your app will be embedded.
